# Issue with dynamic C array

Tags: c

I'm trying to make a dynamic char array, but I'm running into issues. I get segmentation fault when I try to add anything to the array.

```
static int arrays()
   {
    int INITIAL = 1;
    char **all_words;
    all_words = (char**)malloc(INITIAL*sizeof(*all_words));
    int currentSize = INITIAL;

    for(int i = 0; i < counter; i++){
        all_words = realloc(all_words,currentSize*sizeof(*all_words));
        strcpy(all_words[i], "hello");
        currentSize++;
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < counter; i++){
        printf("%s ", all_words[i]);
    }

}
```

I pretty much copied this from a guide online, so I'm not sure why it wouldn't work.

Comment: Don't forget to check that your `malloc` and `realloc` succeeded.

Comment: Are you trying to have a dynamic array of strings, or a dynamic array of char (holding one string)?

Comment: Dynamic array of strings

Comment: Why is INITIAL = 1 when you put nothing in the array? You should start at 0 with all_words = NULL. Increment currentSize before the realloc. Next replace `strcpy` with `strdup` so you actually allocate memory for the strings.

Answer (score 3):

You've correctly allocated an array of `char *`, however those pointers remain uninitiaized.  So when you then do this:

```
strcpy(all_words[i], "hello");
```

You're dereferencing an invalid pointer.

Each element of `all_words` needs to point to allocated space.  This simplest way to do this is to use `strdup` if your system supports it instead of `strcpy`:

```
all_words[i] = strdup("hello");
```

Otherwise you would use `malloc` to allocate the space, then use `strcpy`

```
all_words[i] = malloc(sizeof("hello"));
strcpy(all_words[i], "hello");
```

Comment: Interesting. I recently did this with a struct called Words. Why didn't I need to allocate for every single index for that? 

array = (Words*)realloc(array, sizeof(Words)*++n);

This was enough to do it.

Comment: @code1331  Because a struct (assuming `Words` is a struct) is not a pointer.  When you have an array of pointers, those pointers still need to be set to a valid value before they can be dereferenced.